# Create an instance of a class from another package

Tags: c#

```
using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace assign_5.model
    {
        class Person
        {
       public void t()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("try");
            }
      public string h()
        {
            return "ll";
        }
        }
    }





 using assign_5.model;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace assign_5.Controller
    {
        class FirstNameController
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.t();
            string o = p.h();
     }}
```

Why there is an error in p.t(); and string o = p.h();
"Error  CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'FirstNameController.p'  assign_5    "

Comment: See how `public void t()` exists as a method inside of its class? Ask yourself - where is the equivalent method in `FirstNameController` (hint - you forgot to add it)?

Comment: Put PUBLIC in front of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move your code to a `method` in class, also make class Person as `public` to accessable from another namespace as

```
public class Person{}

class FirstNameController
 {
   void test(){
       Person p = new Person();
       p.t();
       string o = p.h();
   }
}
```

Comment: In future consider marking this as a duplicate of an existing question. This is a common question, and we likely don't need an other answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah that is right I remember now, only in the main class I am allowed to call it directly, I was confused about it, thank you.